# Basic Number Theory Question involving quadratic equations and squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

**Question** : Let  $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$  such that $2m^2 + m = 2n^2 + n$, then prove that $m - n$ and $2m + 2n + 1$
are perfect squares.

$\begin{align}2m^2-2n^2 &=n-m\\
-2(n-m)(m+n) &= n-m \\\end{align}$

If $m-n \neq 0
$\begin{align}\Rightarrow 2(m+n) &=-1  \\
\therefore 2m+2n+1 &=-1+1=0=0^2 \text{ } \blacksquare\\
\end{align}

If $m-n=0$, then $m-n=0=0^2 \text{ } \blacksquare$

Also, Let $2m^2 + m = 2n^2 + n=k$

Clearly, $m,n$ are solutions to the quadratic equation $2x^2+x-k=0$
This implies that $mn=\frac{-k}{2}$
,Implying either $m$ or $n$ is negative which is incorrect as we are given that $m,n \in N$

Therefore to avoid this contradiction it must be that $m=n$ and there exists another root to the equation $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Thus $m-n=0=0^2 \text{  } \blacksquare $

Please just check my solution and tell me if it is correct, if not suggest changes please i wish to learn. Also my main doubt is in the first half of the proof i know it does look very sketchy that the sum of two natural numbers is negative. Thanks a lot for your help and understanding <$3$.

Comment: You have cancelled $n-m$ on both sides without knowing if it's nonzero. Is it given that $m \neq n$? (It *should* be given, though. Otherwise $n = m  = 1$ is a counterexample.)

Comment: You can also observe that the equality never holds for $m,n$ in the natural numbers unless $m = n$. The function $2x^2 + x$ is strictly increasing for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes good observation. Hmm let me see what changes i can make to the solution.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Is this better?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've taken care of the case $m - n = 0$. You have shown that $m - n$ is a perfect square, well and good. But you also need to show that $2m + 2n + 1$ is also a perfect square in this case. You have not done that. (In fact, as my counterexample shows, you *cannot* do that.)

Comment: @paulinho, good point there. But even if $m=n$, then $m-n=0=0^2$ but how can i possible prove that $4m+1=k^2$ for some $k \in N$ seeing as this claim is incorrect in the first place?

Comment: @AayamMathur As Aryaman Maithani observed, the claim is not true. Hence it can't be proven. There has to be a stipulation about whether $m = n$. If it is allowed, then the statement you are trying to prove is wrong and can't be proven. If it isn't allowed, then there are no solutions to your equations in the natural numbers and hence it is true (though meaningless) to say that every solution has $2m + 2n + 1$ and $m - n$ to be perfect squares.

Comment: AryamanMaithani and @paulinho totally understood my mistake. So the question is basically showing that no such m and n exist, right? Could either one of you please provide a written formal proof of the question? Thanks

Comment: @AayamMathur Unfortunately, the scope of the question is unclear. You will have to ask whoever assigned this question whether $m$ can equal $n$. Otherwise, as written (under the assumption that $m = n$ is allowed), the statement is false, by taking say, $m = n = 1$.

Comment: the question is given in an olympiad preparation book of which i have a pdf. Would you like to have a look? Although i have pasted the exact question with mathjax so it wouldn't really be worth your time having a look. Since it can be disproven if $m=n$, What would happen had the restriction $m \neq n$ had been imposed? Would we have said that since it is a strictly increasing function $\forall x$ thus there exist no such $m$ and $n$ where $2m^2+m=2n^2+n$ and thus the given statement (is true as it?) cannot be disproven. Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 2m^2 + m = 2 n^2 + n $$
$$ 2m^2 - 2n^2 + m - n = 0 $$
$$ 2(m^2-n^2) +(m-n) = 0  $$
$$ 2(m+n)(m-n) + (m-n) = 0 $$
$$ ( 2m+2n )(m-n) + 1 (m-n) = 0 $$
$$ (2m+2n+1)(m-n) = 0  $$
With integers, the left factor is odd so nonzero, thus $m=n$

Comment: And now by simply stating that the given statement is false for $m=n=1$ the question is solved. Brilliant. How could be so dumb as to not notice this factorisation lol.